# Android ImageView does not match_parent inside FrameLayout below GingerBread

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-imageview, android-listfragment

I am trying to build a speech bubble for a chat room. Each of the speech bubbles has the attached xml layout.

I am achieving this by setting the **textView** to **wrap_content**, the speech bubble **imageView** to **match_parent** and the **frame_layout** to **wrap_content**. So that the speech_bubble image behind the text **scales according to the amount of text** in the bubble.

I set the width on the textView to match parent and the height to wrap_content and for some reason, it **works perfectly** as required in **Ice Cream Sandwich** (Android 4.1).
However in **Gingerbread** the inner imageView speech bubble **does not scale to match_parent** so that the text can fit neatly inside the bubble. 
In Gingerbread the inner imageView **stays the same size always**, regardless of the text and the **text overflows outside the bubble**. 
Even though the **frameLayout** expands to **wrap_content**, the **imageView** does not **match_parent** as it is supposed to.

Any ideas on why this is happening?  Is there another parameter I can set thru xml or a method I can call programmatically to fix this?

Thanks!

Correct Behavior in ICS:

[Correct Behavior in ICS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71vJn.png)

Incorrect Behavior in GingerBread:
[Incorrect Behavior in GingerBread](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmSP2.jpg)

XML Layout :

```
<merge xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <FrameLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/speech_bubble_framelayout"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:background="@color/color_transparent"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/message_user_imageView">

        <ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                   android:id="@+id/message_background_imageview"
                   android:layout_width="match_parent"
                   android:layout_height="match_parent"
                   android:layout_margin="5dp"
                   android:scaleType="fitXY"
                   android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                   android:textColor="@color/color_brown_mud"
                   android:background="@drawable/chat_bubble_flipped"
                />
        <TextView
                android:id="@+id/message_textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:maxEms="10"
                android:background="@color/color_transparent"
                android:textColor="@color/color_brown_uiDesign_pallete"
                android:textSize="15sp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                android:text="Message"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
                />
    </FrameLayout>
</merge>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

From the looks of it, this is caused by a circular dependency in your sizes: the inner text and image size is dependent on the FrameLayout (`match_parent`), while the FrameLayout's size is dependent on what's contained inside it (`wrap_content`). Use of a FrameLayout is discouraged where more than one child is involved for exactly this sort of reason. For safety, I'd recommend changing the `FrameLayout` to a `RelativeLayout`, and setting the following property on the inner image view:

```
android:layout_alignTop="@+id/message_textview"
android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/message_textview"
```

This will ensure your image always matches up to the size of your text.

Comment: That fixed the issue. I used alignBottom and alignRight with some padding. Thank you!