# Container, Image and Text: How to get it working together?

Tags: android, image, layout

Well, I have a Container, an Image and some Texts (inside another container), this way:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/btn">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_left"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                custom:fontStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeSmall"
                android:text="Header" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                custom:fontStyle="regular"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textSizeMicro"
                android:text="Body" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

The image associated with ImageView (yes, it is a background image) is bigger than the height of all text together. Thus, I would like to "crop" it inside RelativeLayout. **But that ImageView always take full size when I set it to fill_parent. :(**

What can I do?

P.S.: I already tried to use that image as background of `RelativeLayout`. Not working also.

Pleaaase, help!!

Comment: You want LinearLayout over ImageView ?? Please explain exactly what you want with sketch or something.

Comment: @Richard post the full code

Comment: Yes, LinearLayout is over ImageView.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to wrap content views rather than background drawable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4312133/how-to-wrap-content-views-rather-than-background-drawable)

Answer (score 1):

Use `FrameLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout` to get background image with same size of textview.

**Edit**

I've got answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12434762/android-imageview-does-not-match-parent-inside-framelayout-below-gingerbread#12434801) . You can do it with `RelativeLayout` by using `layout_alignTop` and `layout_alignBottom`. Sorry for my first wrong answer.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:src="@drawable/background"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/text_container"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/text_container"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left">

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Header" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:text="Body" />
    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it will be useful for you.

Comment: What's the big deal with `FrameLayout` ?

Comment: You can overlap each child by setting `layout_gravity` in `Framelayout`.

Comment: It doesn't work, because ImageView stays with its default height (bigger than TextViews). ImageView is not cropping to fit its container (in this case, `FrameLayout`.

Comment: @Richard . I've got right answer. How will I post it ?? Can I updated my answer ??

Answer (score -1):

I find an answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19405297/406110

Well, basically `ImageView` is aligned to `top`, `bottom`, `left` and `right` to the container with `TextViews` and `heigth` and `width` is k.